# Optimizing CSS animation for SVG map with hundreds of markers

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I have a custom SVG map with about 320 dot markers. I am trying to do some animations on the markers. The first is having them sprinkle load via an opacity animation (eventually add some other animations after the initial load like having one randomly glow every second or so).

[Example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/ashwebstudio/pen/YzrgbMN)

After page load, the JS adds the CSS animation with a custom delay to each of the markers. When I put this on a page, the whole browser gets clunky and won't scroll and my CPU starts making all kinds of noises so somehow this needs to be better optimized to not kill users' computers. In CodePen, for some reason, it doesn't seem to cause as bad of a problem but the animation does become clunky for the second half of markers.

I have tried using jQuery animate and that didn't help as I had the same performance issues.

Is the problem simply too many markers?

HTML

```
<div id="map">
    <div class="container">
          <!-- SVG CODE IS HERE, SEE CodePen as it is too big to fit here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#map { 
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(77,75,75,1) 0%, rgba(47,47,47,1) 100%); 
  padding: 50px; 
}
#markers circle { 
  fill: #4ca7fc; 
  stroke: rgba(255,255,255,0.44); 
  stroke-width: 1; 
  opacity: 0; 
}
@keyframes enter {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
      opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

JS (using jQuery)

```
var animation_delay = 0;
jQuery( '#markers circle' ).each(function(){
  animation_delay += .01;
  jQuery( this ).css( 'animation', 'enter 1s ease-out ' + animation_delay + 's normal 1 forwards' );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by putting the  map markers in  groups of 10 within the SVG file. Then I did the fade-in animation on the groups instead of individual markers. This changed it from 320 animations to 32 and helped the performance significantly.

Answer (score 0):

### Path complexity vs. pixels

In your case a rastered/pixel based map background could also improve rendering performance.

The world map svg alone has ~200KB and ~7800 path segments.
Quite a lot of work for the svg renderer (even on a desktop I see a map progressively rendering continents).

In comparison a 2600x1422px png8 with transparency could be reduced to ~60KB.

You might use a `srcset` for different viewports like so:

```
    <img id="mapBG" class="mapBG" src="map-480px.png" srcset="map_480px.png 480w, map_640px.png 640w, map_vector.svg 2400w" alt="map">
```

### Simplify filters

Svg filters are pretty advanced but tend to be quite expensive regarding rendering performance – particularly when applied on loads of elements.
Maybe you could achieve a visually similar result with css properties.

### Delayed rendering of markers

Loading your map bg by a cachable `<img>` element might be a good advice if you want to use this map multiple times on your website/app.

Thus, your markers should start popping up after the map background has been loaded completely and rendered.

### Example

This snippet takes a downsized png converted to a data-URL

```js
let mapBG = document.querySelector("#mapBG");
let src = mapBG.src;

function addMapMarkers() {
  let markers = document.querySelectorAll("#markers circle");
  let animationDelay = 0;
  markers.forEach(function(el, i) {
    el.classList.add("marker-animation");
    el.setAttribute("style", "animation-delay:" + animationDelay + "s");
    animationDelay += 0.01;
  });
}
checkMapLoad(mapBG);
async function checkMapLoad(img) {
  // Wait for the img src to load.
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    img.onload = resolve;
  });
  // src is loaded but let's add some extra delay for rendering
  console.log("map is loaded");
  img.classList.add("mapFadeIn");
  setTimeout(function() {
    addMapMarkers();
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#map {
  background: radial-gradient( circle, rgba(77, 75, 75, 1) 0%, rgba(47, 47, 47, 1) 100%);
  padding: 50px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.mapBG {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.mapFadeIn {
  animation: fadeIn 1s forwards;
}

.marker {
  fill: #4ca7fc;
  stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  stroke-width: 1;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3));
  opacity: 0;
}

.marker-animation {
  animation-name: enter;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
}

@keyframes enter {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="map" class="mapWrap">
  <div class="container">
    <img id="mapBG" class="mapBG" src='data:image/png;base64,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'
      data-srcset="map_480px.png 480w, map_640px.png 640w, map_vector.svg 2400w" alt="map">

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1300  711 ">
      <g id="markers" class="markers">
        <circle cx="172.0056" cy="281.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1093.0056" cy="281.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="670.0056" cy="247.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="598.0056" cy="229.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="586.0056" cy="285.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="169.0056" cy="264.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1090.0056" cy="264.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="855.0056" cy="347.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="667.0056" cy="230.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="595.0056" cy="212.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="219.0056" cy="335.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1087.0056" cy="318.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="905.0056" cy="418.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="717.0056" cy="301.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="607.0056" cy="280.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="178.0056" cy="297.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1099.0056" cy="297.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="676.0056" cy="263.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="604.0056" cy="245.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="228.0056" cy="368.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="202.0056" cy="297.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1123.0056" cy="297.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="888.0056" cy="380.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="700.0056" cy="263.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="628.0056" cy="245.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="252.0056" cy="368.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="313.0056" cy="306.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="263.0056" cy="302.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="260.0056" cy="291.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="269.0056" cy="309.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="277.0056" cy="288.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="292.0056" cy="303.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="280.0056" cy="295.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="293.0056" cy="279.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="280.0056" cy="295.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="328.0056" cy="292.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="331.0056" cy="278.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="325.0056" cy="271.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="169.0056" cy="289.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1108.0056" cy="302.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="667.0056" cy="255.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="595.0056" cy="237.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="219.0056" cy="360.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="583.0056" cy="293.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="166.0056" cy="272.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1087.0056" cy="272.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="664.0056" cy="238.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="592.0056" cy="220.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="157.0056" cy="270.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1039.0056" cy="254.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="655.0056" cy="236.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="583.0056" cy="218.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="216.0056" cy="343.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1084.0056" cy="328.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1088.0056" cy="519.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1051.0056" cy="417.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="991.0056" cy="414.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1024.0056" cy="464.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1239.0056" cy="619.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1242.0056" cy="634.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1135.0056" cy="640.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1107.0056" cy="599.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1158.0056" cy="579.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1164.0056" cy="410.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1152.0056" cy="608.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1134.0056" cy="625.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="902.0056" cy="426.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="714.0056" cy="309.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="377.0056" cy="525.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="371.0056" cy="513.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="334.0056" cy="485.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="359.0056" cy="582.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="396.0056" cy="599.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="407.0056" cy="599.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="606.0056" cy="417.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="673.0056" cy="531.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="697.0056" cy="487.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="745.0056" cy="470.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="681.0056" cy="596.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="589.0056" cy="279.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="175.0056" cy="305.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1096.0056" cy="305.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="649.0056" cy="256.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="601.0056" cy="253.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="225.0056" cy="376.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="163.0056" cy="293.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1088.0056" cy="308.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="661.0056" cy="259.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="589.0056" cy="241.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="213.0056" cy="364.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="169.0056" cy="301.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1090.0056" cy="301.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="667.0056" cy="267.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="595.0056" cy="249.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="219.0056" cy="372.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="199.0056" cy="305.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1120.0056" cy="305.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="885.0056" cy="388.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="697.0056" cy="271.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="625.0056" cy="253.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="249.0056" cy="376.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="310.0056" cy="314.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="301.0056" cy="304.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="295.0056" cy="327.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="307.0056" cy="345.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="263.0056" cy="336.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="217.0056" cy="324.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1033.0056" cy="330.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="903.0056" cy="407.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="715.0056" cy="290.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="643.0056" cy="272.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="193.0056" cy="314.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1101.0056" cy="313.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="879.0056" cy="397.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="691.0056" cy="280.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="619.0056" cy="262.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="243.0056" cy="385.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="190.0056" cy="293.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1111.0056" cy="293.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="688.0056" cy="259.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="616.0056" cy="241.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="240.0056" cy="364.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="181.0056" cy="271.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1102.0056" cy="271.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="867.0056" cy="354.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="679.0056" cy="237.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="607.0056" cy="219.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="231.0056" cy="342.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="169.0056" cy="252.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1090.0056" cy="252.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="667.0056" cy="218.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="595.0056" cy="200.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="219.0056" cy="323.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1030.0056" cy="316.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="905.0056" cy="406.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="717.0056" cy="289.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="645.0056" cy="271.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="220.0056" cy="226.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="646.0056" cy="174.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="295.0056" cy="241.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="325.0056" cy="300.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="316.0056" cy="298.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="393.0056" cy="402.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="349.0056" cy="383.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="340.0056" cy="383.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="337.0056" cy="376.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="323.0056" cy="375.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="390.0056" cy="390.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="390.0056" cy="386.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="390.0056" cy="383.6911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="390.0056" cy="383.6911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="322.0056" cy="284.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="181.0056" cy="284.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1082.0056" cy="282.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="867.0056" cy="367.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="679.0056" cy="250.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="607.0056" cy="232.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="231.0056" cy="355.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="178.0056" cy="267.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1099.0056" cy="267.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="676.0056" cy="233.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="604.0056" cy="215.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="228.0056" cy="338.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="187.0056" cy="300.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1108.0056" cy="300.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="685.0056" cy="266.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="613.0056" cy="248.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="237.0056" cy="371.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="211.0056" cy="300.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1132.0056" cy="300.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="930.0056" cy="371.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="709.0056" cy="266.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="637.0056" cy="248.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="647.0056" cy="242.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="193.0056" cy="284.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1126.0056" cy="287.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="691.0056" cy="250.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="619.0056" cy="232.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="322.0056" cy="309.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="307.0056" cy="322.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="319.0056" cy="340.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="313.0056" cy="334.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="349.0056" cy="420.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="328.0056" cy="420.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="334.0056" cy="432.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="275.0056" cy="331.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="229.0056" cy="319.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="205.0056" cy="309.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1111.0056" cy="307.1937" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="891.0056" cy="392.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="703.0056" cy="275.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="631.0056" cy="257.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="202.0056" cy="288.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1123.0056" cy="288.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="888.0056" cy="371.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="700.0056" cy="254.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="628.0056" cy="236.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="252.0056" cy="359.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="193.0056" cy="266.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1120.0056" cy="279.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="691.0056" cy="232.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="619.0056" cy="214.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="243.0056" cy="337.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="181.0056" cy="247.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1137.0056" cy="283.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="679.0056" cy="213.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="607.0056" cy="195.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="232.0056" cy="221.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="307.0056" cy="236.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="337.0056" cy="295.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="340.0056" cy="281.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="349.0056" cy="270.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="340.0056" cy="269.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="346.0056" cy="264.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="346.0056" cy="275.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="349.0056" cy="269.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="413.0056" cy="249.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="343.0056" cy="246.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="334.0056" cy="223.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="178.0056" cy="292.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1099.0056" cy="292.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="703.0056" cy="245.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="676.0056" cy="258.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="604.0056" cy="240.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="228.0056" cy="363.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="175.0056" cy="275.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1105.0056" cy="296.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="673.0056" cy="241.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="601.0056" cy="223.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="225.0056" cy="346.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="603.0056" cy="288.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="184.0056" cy="308.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1064.0056" cy="297.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="976.0056" cy="387.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="994.0056" cy="487.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1030.0056" cy="605.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="682.0056" cy="274.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="610.0056" cy="256.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="234.0056" cy="379.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="208.0056" cy="308.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1094.0056" cy="309.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="922.0056" cy="371.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="706.0056" cy="274.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="634.0056" cy="256.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="646.0056" cy="262.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="199.0056" cy="317.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1033.0056" cy="302.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="885.0056" cy="400.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="697.0056" cy="283.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="625.0056" cy="265.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="319.0056" cy="317.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="317.0056" cy="317.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="319.0056" cy="309.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="315.0056" cy="306.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="319.0056" cy="314.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="365.0056" cy="423.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="343.0056" cy="438.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="331.0056" cy="441.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="304.0056" cy="330.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="316.0056" cy="348.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="312.0056" cy="342.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="281.0056" cy="382.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="295.0056" cy="369.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="286.0056" cy="370.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="292.0056" cy="393.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="310.0056" cy="408.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="304.0056" cy="414.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="272.0056" cy="339.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="238.0056" cy="377.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="226.0056" cy="327.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="652.0056" cy="275.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="202.0056" cy="317.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1036.0056" cy="340.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="962.0056" cy="374.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="888.0056" cy="400.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="700.0056" cy="283.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="628.0056" cy="265.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="252.0056" cy="388.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="199.0056" cy="296.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1120.0056" cy="296.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="885.0056" cy="379.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="697.0056" cy="262.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="625.0056" cy="244.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="672.0056" cy="194.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="675.0056" cy="197.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="249.0056" cy="367.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="190.0056" cy="274.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1120.0056" cy="288.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="688.0056" cy="240.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="616.0056" cy="222.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="240.0056" cy="345.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="178.0056" cy="255.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1099.0056" cy="255.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="676.0056" cy="221.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="604.0056" cy="203.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="163.0056" cy="256.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="1084.0056" cy="256.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="661.0056" cy="222.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="589.0056" cy="204.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="228.0056" cy="326.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="229.0056" cy="229.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="304.0056" cy="244.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="334.0056" cy="303.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="328.0056" cy="308.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="322.0056" cy="308.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="334.0056" cy="304.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="328.0056" cy="301.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="316.0056" cy="298.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="304.0056" cy="288.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="292.0056" cy="283.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="274.0056" cy="268.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="289.0056" cy="293.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="290.0056" cy="269.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="334.0056" cy="287.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="316.0056" cy="290.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="284.0056" cy="281.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="68.0056" cy="145.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="38.0056" cy="165.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
        <circle cx="78.0056" cy="175.1911" r="3" class="marker" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```